# MYSQL finding time span between two dates/times

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a table that has two fields dt(DateTime) and isblocked(Bit)

[image]

What I've been trying to do is find the time span between two dates/times where there is 45 mins continuously free - based on a start date/time.

for example: based on the table above using 2012-12-11 13:30:00' as my start date.
I would need values like this:

```
2012-12-11 15:30:00
2012-12-11 16:45:00
```

I have tried some min and max queries, like:

```
SELECT MIN(dt), isbooked
FROM booking
WHERE dt >= '2012-12-11 13:30:00' AND isbooked = 1
GROUP BY dt
LIMIT 1;
```

But I can't seem to get the right structure together. If more information is needed just let me know.

Comment: How do you know how long a booking is?  Is it simply convention that each one is 15 minutes, is each booking "in effect" until the next one starts, or is there another column which indicates the duration of the booking?

Comment: Could you post the sample data in a copy-paste friendly format?

Comment: Hi Matt and thanks for taking the time to read my question, each booking time could be 30 min, or more in 30 or 45 min intervals that's why I set it up with 15 min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL you can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select min(b.dt) as StartTime, NotBookedTime as EndTime
from (select b.*,
             (select min(b2.dt) from booking b2 where b2.dt >= b.dt and b2.isbooked = 1
             ) as NotBookedTime
      from booking b
     ) b
where b.isbooked = 0
group by NotBookedTime
having date_add(min(b.dt), interval 45 minute) <=  NotBookedTime
```

What this does is find the first booked interval for each record, and remembers the time.  It then finds the first booked interval, and checks when the difference is 45 minutes or larger.

Comment: Hi Gordon and thanks for your answer!  I'll will give this a try and report back ASAP I knew this was going to be a little more then a basic query..  but I see were what you did and its very cool..

Comment: The only syntax error was that I wrote `45 minutes` instead of `45 minute`.  The query does work.

Answer (score 1):

This also should work:

```
SELECT d.dt
FROM (
  SELECT
    t1.dt,
    MIN(case when t2.isBooked then t2.dt end) AS next_booked,
    MAX(case when not t2.isBooked then t2.dt end) as max_unbooked
  FROM times t1 INNER JOIN times t2 ON t1.dt < t2.dt
  WHERE t1.isBooked =0
  GROUP BY t1.dt
) d
WHERE
  timediff(next_booked,d.dt)>='00:45:00' or
  (next_booked is null and timediff(max_unbooked,d.dt)>='00:30:00')
```

dependin on what you are after, it could also be simplified like this:

```
SELECT d.dt
FROM (
  SELECT
    t1.dt,
    MIN(t2.dt) as next_booked
  FROM times t1 left  JOIN times t2 ON t1.dt < t2.dt and t2.isBooked=1
  WHERE t1.isBooked =0
  GROUP BY t1.dt
) d
WHERE timediff(d.next_booked, d.dt)>='00:45:00'
      or d.next_booked is null
GROUP BY d.next_booked
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae34b/9)

```
SELECT min(b.dt) AS StartTime, NotBookedTime AS EndTime
FROM (SELECT b.*,
        (SELECT min(b2.dt) FROM DT b2 
           WHERE b2.dt >= b.dt AND b2.isBooked = 1
         ) AS NotBookedTime
     FROM DT b
    ) b
WHERE b.isBooked = 0
GROUP BY NotBookedTime
HAVING EndTime is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Variable:

```
set @tp=now();
SELECT @tp:=dt as dt,isbooked FROM booking WHERE 
    dt >= addtime(@tp,'00:45:00') AND isbooked = 1
    ORDER BY dt;
```

where `@TP` it will take value of the previous date selected.